# How to disable/configure Nuxt+Fastify request debug logs?

Tags: logging, configuration, nuxt.js, fastify

I'm using Nuxt@2.12.2 with the baked in Fastify@1.14.6 back-end. The app itself is working nicely but I'm always getting a lot of the following request log in dev mode:

```
{"level":30,"time":1590835320846,"msg":"incoming request","pid":72306,"hostname":"mark","reqId":11,"req":{"id":11,"method":"GET","url":"/_nuxt/pages/students/index.js","hostname":"127.0.0.1:3020","remoteAddress":"127.0.0.1","remotePort":49624},"v":1}
{"level":30,"time":1590835320848,"msg":"request completed","pid":72306,"hostname":"mark","reqId":11,"res":{"statusCode":200},"responseTime":2.8058980107307434,"v":1}
{"level":30,"time":1590835321270,"msg":"incoming request","pid":72306,"hostname":"mark","reqId":12,"req":{"id":12,"method":"GET","url":"/__webpack_hmr/client","hostname":"127.0.0.1:3020","remoteAddress":"127.0.0.1","remotePort":49624},"v":1}
{"level":30,"time":1590835321741,"msg":"incoming request","pid":72306,"hostname":"mark","reqId":13,"req":{"id":13,"method":"GET","url":"/_nuxt/manifest.84b2e439.json","hostname":"127.0.0.1:3020","remoteAddress":"127.0.0.1","remotePort":49633},"v":1}
{"level":30,"time":1590835321742,"msg":"incoming request","pid":72306,"hostname":"mark","reqId":14,"req":{"id":14,"method":"GET","url":"/_nuxt/icons/icon_64.5f6a36.png","hostname":"127.0.0.1:3020","remoteAddress":"127.0.0.1","remotePort":49610},"v":1}
{"level":30,"time":1590835321743,"msg":"request completed","pid":72306,"hostname":"mark","reqId":13,"res":{"statusCode":200},"responseTime":1.8973180055618286,"v":1}
{"level":30,"time":1590835321744,"msg":"request completed","pid":72306,"hostname":"mark","reqId":14,"res":{"statusCode":200},"responseTime":2.007888972759247,"v":1}
{"level":30,"time":1590835321767,"msg":"incoming request","pid":72306,"hostname":"mark","reqId":15,"req":{"id":15,"method":"GET","url":"/_nuxt/icons/icon_144.5f6a36.png","hostname":"127.0.0.1:3020","remoteAddress":"127.0.0.1","remotePort":49610},"v":1}
{"level":30,"time":1590835321769,"msg":"request completed","pid":72306,"hostname":"mark","reqId":15,"res":{"statusCode":200},"responseTime":1.3589969873428345,"v":1}
```

I there a way to disable or modify this? Gets in the way of debugging at times. I tried looking for a configuration documentation related to this but can't seem to find one with the keywords I've tried.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
Eventually found the answer. In `src/index.js`, fastify is initialized there. Config is fed directly. Logging can be turned off by feeding `{ logger: false }` to fastify instantiation. I modified it to get the config from `nuxt.config.js` instead.

```
// Import and Set Nuxt.js options
const config = require('../nuxt.config.js')
config.dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'

const fastify = require('fastify')(config.fastify)
```

and added a fastify section in `nuxt.config.js`

Answer (score 2):

In the latest version of fastify 3.0, you can disable request logging for every route by setting disableRequestLogging option to true

```
const server = fastify({'disableRequestLogging' :true});

server.listen(8085, '0.0.0.0', (err, address) => {
    if (err) {
        console.warn(err);
        process.exit(1);
    }
    console.warn(`Server listening at ${address}`);
});
```

Here the link https://www.fastify.io/docs/latest/Server/#disablerequestlogging

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I realize now that I didn't provide the version for fastify baked into Nuxt. It's 1.14.6. My apologies for this

I eventually found that Nuxt isn't loading fastify configs the usual way(nuxt.config.js). The config is defined instead in its entry point. Logging can be turned off by feeding `{ logger: false }` from there.